# (Co-) Homology of free nilpotent Lie Algebras

Tags: lie-algebras

What is actually known about the (co-) homology of free nilpotent Lie Algebras over $\mathbb{C}$ and coefficients also in $\mathbb{C}$?
I.e. the nilpotent Lie Algebras that one gets by a quotient of a free Lie algebra by some part of its descending central series.

Answer (score 2):

There are several results on the homology of free-nilpotent Lie algebras with trivial coefficients, in particular for free two-step nilpotent Lie algebras.
[Stefan Sigg](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=11&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjEy9Ovw4vMAhXIAJoKHeIOD744ChAWCB0wAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sciencedirect.com%2Fscience%2Farticle%2Fpii%2FS0021869396903178&usg=AFQjCNHaKO0ERq2QVkqiqqVBW8JVFv-r4w&sig2=cfycNTkpSgenPF7IuUJOyw) has determined the homology in this case by working
out the structure of the homology as a module under the general linear group. The main tool is a Laplacian for the free two-step nilpotent Lie algebras, which turns out to be closely related to the Casimir operator of the general linear group. In addition, [Grassberger, King, Tirao](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=12&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjEy9Ovw4vMAhXIAJoKHeIOD744ChAWCCcwAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sciencedirect.com%2Fscience%2Farticle%2Fpii%2FS002186930200090X&usg=AFQjCNFAus8uf73-fqywcgRybBTkI_6cQA&sig2=oiHZoGDNU67w24HJZq-MnQ) give
an explicit formula for the total dimension of the homology of a free 2-step
nilpotent Lie algebra.